# HDFS not formatting, but no errors

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I'm setting up a Hadoop clusters on 4 nodes (3 slaves), all individual EC2s within a VPC. Roughly following these steps (but installed Hadoop 2.8.1 instead): http://arturmkrtchyan.com/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-2-yarn-cluster

I formatted the namenode, which gave the response below:

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
17/09/26 07:05:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   user = hduser
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/10.0.0.190
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.8.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/...

STARTUP_MSG:   build = Unknown -r Unknown; compiled by 'hduser' on 2017-09-22T14:53Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_144
************************************************************/
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
Formatting using clusterid: CID-15524170-7dfa-481b-add9-4c2542a55ca5
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSEditLog: Edit logging is async:false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: KeyProvider: null
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair: true
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Detailed lock hold time metrics enabled: false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2017 Sep 26 07:07:33
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 3
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hduser (auth:SIMPLE)
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
17/09/26 07:07:33 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occurring more than 10 times
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
17/09/26 07:07:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode ? (Y or N) 
$ Y
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-793961451-10.0.0.190-1506409761821
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode has been successfully formatted.
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 323 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
17/09/26 07:09:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/10.0.0.190
************************************************************/
```

When I start dfs and yarn it seems to start up correctly:

```
$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com: starting namenode, logging to ...
10.0.0.185: starting datanode, logging to ...
10.0.0.244: starting datanode, logging to ...
10.0.0.83: starting datanode, logging to ...
Starting secondary namenodes [ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com: starting secondarynamenode, logging to ...


$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to ...
10.0.0.185: starting nodemanager, logging to ...
10.0.0.83: starting nodemanager, logging to ...
10.0.0.244: starting nodemanager, logging to ...

$ jps
14326 NameNode
14998 Jps
14552 SecondaryNameNode
14729 ResourceManager
```

And on the other nodes something like:

```
15880 Jps
15563 DataNode
15693 NodeManager
```

But when I try to write data to HDFS, it tells me that none of the nodes is actually available. It seems a very generic error, and I can't find what went wrong.

```
$ hdfs dfs -put pg1661.txt /samples/input
WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /samples/input/pg1661.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Then, when I check the status, it does not seem to work correctly:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0
```

I checked the log files, and they don't indicate any (FATAL) errors, except when trying to upload the file.

Given that above does not produce any errors at start-up and the error message itself is quite generic, I find it difficult to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

From your "hdfs dfsadmin -report" command output which shows capacity as 0. It looks like you may have forgotten to format namenode. You need to run below command before you start HDFS.

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

After this "hdfs dfsadmin -report" output should look similar to below,

```
Configured Capacity: 32195477504 (29.98 GB)
Present Capacity: 29190479872 (27.19 GB)
DFS Remaining: 29190471680 (27.19 GB)
DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0
```

I have a single node setup video tutorial on below link. Hope it will help you. This is for Hadoop version 2.8.1,

http://hadooptutorials.info/2017/09/14/hadoop-installation-on-signle-node-cluster/

Comment: Thx for your reply. I did run this command. The response ends with `SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ec2-xx-xx-xx-01.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/10.0.0.190`. Does this indicate that the format command failed? It does not give any error messages, except for telling me that it shut down. I will update the question.

Comment: I included the response I got when I (tried to) format the namenode.

Comment: I think Shutting Down message is normal when you format namenode. I am thinking may be namenode not able to SSH into data nodes. Do you have data nodes defined as separate server or same server?. May be you can try doing single node setup first, i.e. both namenode and data node on same server. Once it works try adding other data nodes. It will isolate few issues. Also can you share your masters and slaves file alongwith core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml?